# Google Apps Scripts QR Codes not Scanning

Tags: google-apps-script, qr-code, barcode-scanner, scanning

I have create a photo request app for our buyers to submit to the photo studio.  They enter specific information and a document is created with the sku as a QR code. This is then tagged to the product and delivered to the photo studio.  The photo studio can then scan the qr code and it fills the form for stylist and photographers to view the instructions from the buyer.

The form is published to a Google site.  It is executed as me.  And is accessible by anyone within our domain.

The folder is shared with the domain where the temporary document to print the  QR code is stored.

My problem is that when I print the QR code it will scan and when anyone else prints the QR code it will not scan.  I have signed in on their computers and it works fine and when they sign in on my computer it will not scan.  It seems to be tied to my sign on but I not sure what to try next

The code for to build the QR code is below.

```
function getQRCode(e,record, sSku){
    Logger.log("getQRCode start");
    var img = "";
    var wb = SpreadsheetApp.openById(e.parameter.submitKey);
    var ss = wb.getSheetByName("Responses");
    var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();
    var lastCol = ss.getLastColumn();
    var arData = ss.getRange(1, 3, lastRow).getValues();
    var list = arData.splice(",");
    var len = list.length;
    for(var i=0; i<len;i++){
        if(i>0 ){
           var val = list[i];
           if(val==record){
               var n= ss.getRange(i+1, 1).activate().getRow();
               var sku = ss.getRange(n,16).getValue();
               if(sku == sSku){
                  var bc = ss.getRange(n, lastCol-1, 1, 1).getValue();

                  var sUrl = "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?            chs=100x100&cht=qr&chl=" + bc;

                 Logger.log(sUrl);
                 var img = UrlFetchApp.fetch(sUrl).getAs("image/png"); 
                  break;
             }
          } 
      }
    }

  Logger.log("getQRCode end");
  return img;
 }
```

Comment: Okay screwed up on the formatting on the code and part of it appears in the comments

Comment: So, in every case the code will print?  Have you checked the folder/file permissions at the URL where the img is being fetched?  If the variable assignment for sUrl is on two lines, I'd try putting everything on one line of code.  Instead of putting `.getAs` at the end of the fetch, I'd be curious to know what is getting returned without that?  You can specify content type in the `Advanced parameters` of fetch.  fetch(url, params)  [Google Documentation fetch](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object))

Comment: If the variable assignment for sUrl is on two lines, (cbs) it is all on one line, I am not sure why it shows with the break in the line above.

Comment: The document is created in a drive folder where I am the owner of the document with users having edit rights. If you open one of the documents that a buyer creates through the interface the image of the QR code is identical on all their documents.  The app is being published and executed as myself so it is as if I am call the code to create the graph and image.